# Determine interval with known total and number of points

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Doing some volunteer work for a non-profit, I recently had a problem that I couldn't easily figure out:

I had a dollar total of funds pledged for the year ($150,000), and I knew the total number of pledges (90), and I wanted to see what it would look like if the pledges were distributed evenly from zero to X until the amount had been reached with each increment being the same.

So, for instance if we had $15 raised among 5 pledgers, the even distribution would be 1,2,3,4,5.  And I wanted to do it in all in excel, because small non-profit.

Comment: Why not **3,3,3,3,3** ??

Comment: Sorry, I should have added that the numbers have to increment by an equal amount!

Comment: @cmcnulty  you are basically looking at the sum of an arithmetic series or at least that is what I think of it as.  According to this [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression) on the subject.  You basically need to solve for d in the wiki formulas, remember that a1 is zero, Sn is your total pledges, and n is your number of pleges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your provided data setup (Number of backers in cell A1, total pledged amount in cell A2), use this formula in cell C1 and copy down:

```
=ROW()*$A$2/((1+$A$1)*$A$1/2)
```

Note that this formula will give you different results than your original.  However, it will provide correct results, just as yours does.

Comment: I'm shocked at how simple the solution is - especially since that's the track I was on (using the "how to count all the numbers of 1-100" formula).  I just went off the deep-end somewhere along the line.

Comment: Basically the only difference between my gigantic formula and yours is that mine starts at row 1 with 1/2 the increment value, and then spends the rest of the time trying to catch up. Math.

Answer (score 1):

This is easy using **Solver**, we will put the 90 pledges in **A1** through **A90** and the increment in **B1**.  Lets guess that the increment is **1** so we put that in **B1**.

in **A1** we enter:  **1**
In **A2** we enter the formula:

```
=A1+$B$1
```

and copy down through **A90**
In **A91** we enter:

```
=SUM(A1:A90)
```

[image]

Clearly this is way off from the desired 150,000
We can use Solver to adjust the value in **B1** to get the desired result in **A91**:

[image]

The value Solver gets in **B1** is  *37.4307116107366*
We naturally would round this to two digits to get a good approximate solution

Comment: @cmcnulty  Thanks, but tigeravatar's answer is the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

In a spreadsheet enter as A1 the number of "steps" in my case, pledgers as cell A1.  In A2 enter the total you hope to reach. In my example $150,000. Finally in C1 enter the following formula:

```
= 2 *( ( (-1 * (2 * $A$1 * (ROW()) )) + ( 4 * (ROW()) * $A$2 ) + POWER( $A$1, 2 ) + $A$1 - ( 2 * $A$2 ))/( POWER( 2 * $A$1, 2 ) ) )
```

And then drag that column down the number of rows equal to your number of steps in A1.  If you tally those values, it should equal the value in A2.

You'll notice that I use the ROW() function - if you'd like to start this on row other than row 1, you'll need to adjust the two calls to ROW to subtract the row you're on so that it equals 1 (and wrap it in parantheses) for instance here's the same function started on row 5 - note the "(ROW()-4)":

```
= 2 *( ( (-1 * (2 * $A$1 * (ROW()-4) )) + ( 4 * (ROW()-4) * $A$2 ) + POWER( $A$1, 2 ) + $A$1 - ( 2 * $A$2 ))/( POWER( 2 * $A$1, 2 ) ) )
```

Comment: I'd be interested to hear easier or more elegant ways of solving the problem as outlined in the question - the solution I found works for me, but it seems like something Excel would provide an easier solution to.